# Zindex Not working properly

Tags: html, css, tags, nav

I have a website you can visit at http://www.ssdpsjal.tk

As you can see when you visit the website using PC, the navigation menu appears on the loader. Why is this happening?

I have only added the following lines to my css:-

```
<style>
.navbar-inverse {
   background-color: #3A1F3B;
   border-color: #222222;
}

.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

And a class to call it->
`<nav class="MY_OLD_CLASSES + nav nav_inverse">`

I have added nothing else, please help me fix the problem.

Help Appreciated

**EDIT**

My full code is

```
<style>
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #3A1F3B;
  border-color: #222222;
}

.navbar {}
</style>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse nav-bar-main" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="main-navigation clearfix visible-md visible-lg" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="main-menu sf-menu">

                       <?php 
                                            foreach ($main as $lvl1){
                                                if(strpos($lvl1->href, 'http') !== false){ $lvl1_link = $lvl1->href;} else {$lvl1_link = link_url().$lvl1->href;}                                                   
                                                echo '<li><a href="'.$lvl1_link.'">'.$lvl1->title.'</a>';

                                                If ($lvl1->dropdown == "1"){
                                                    echo '<ul class="sub-menu" style="width:300px;">';                                                      
                                                    foreach ($sub as $lvl2){
                                                        If ($lvl2->mid == $lvl1->id){
                                                            If ($lvl2->dropdown == "1"){

                                                                if(strpos($lvl2->href, 'http') !== false){$lvl2_link = $lvl2->href;} else {$lvl2_link = link_url().$lvl2->href;}                                                                    
                                                                echo '<li><a href="'.$lvl2_link.'">'.$lvl2->title.'</a><ul class="sub-menu">';
                                                                foreach($subsub as $lvl3){
                                                                    If ($lvl3->mid == $lvl2->id){

                                                                        if(strpos($lvl3->href, 'http') !== false){$lvl3_link = $lvl3->href;} else {$lvl3_link = link_url().$lvl3->href;}                                                                            
                                                                        echo '<li><a href="'.$lvl3_link.'">'.$lvl3->title.'</a></li>';
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                echo '</ul></li>';
                                                                }else{
                                                                if(strpos($lvl2->href, 'http') !== false){$lvl2_link = $lvl2->href;} else {$lvl2_link = link_url().$lvl2->href;}
                                                                echo '<li><a href="'.$lvl2_link.'">'.$lvl2->title.'</a></li>';
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    echo '</ul>';
                                                }
                                                echo '</li>';
                                            }
                                        ?>

                    </ul> <!-- /.main-menu -->

            </nav> <!-- /.main-navigation -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div> <!-- /.nav-bar-main -->
```

**EDIT 2**

If I remove navbar and navbar-inverse classes, the problem is fixed but i don't want the UI to change so I cant remove them.

Comment: Remove margin bottom from css

Comment: still no luck, it is still the same

Comment: @Webmaster post your full code

Comment: Could u plz create a fiddle, i will fix for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding class `loaded` to body, you can do:

```
body:not(.loaded) .navbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for this, it solved my literally 83 :) more problems

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. (My bad, I did not see it before :(  )

According to my JQuery navbar and navbar-inverse were already occupied somwhere else so I simply used `style=""` tag